# $f\circ f=g$ revisited

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, fractional-iteration

This may be related to [solving $f(f(x))=g(x)$](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/17614). Let
$C(\mathbb{R})$ be the linear space of all continuous functions from
$\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$, and let $\mathcal{S}:=\{g\in C(\mathbb{R}) ; \exists\; f\in C(\mathbb{R})$ s.t. $f\circ f=g \}$ . Is there some infinite dimensional (or, at least,
bidimensional) linear subspace of $C(\mathbb{R})$ contained in $\mathcal{S}$
?

P.S. As a remark, there is a [maybe] interesting connection between
[How to solve $f(f(x)) = \cos(x)$?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/17605) and [Borsuk pairs of Banach spaces](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/11675) .
Namely, let $E$ be the closed subspace of $C[-1,1]$ consisting of
all even functions, and let $K$ be the closed unit ball of $E$.
Then the continuous mapping $\Psi:$ $K$ $\rightarrow$ $E$ expressed
by $\Psi(f)$ $:=$ $f\circ f$ $+$ $\left(\left\Vert f\right\Vert _{\infty}-1\right)\cdot\cos$

is odd on $\partial K$, and has no zeros in $K$.

Comment: ad least there is a 2-dimensional cone (a space which is closed under linear combinations with positive coefficients) given by the space of all nondecreasing linear maps.

Comment: All increasing bijections are ok, so there is an infinite-dimensional cone.


Comment: Unfortunately, not even two vectors in that cone generate a subspace in ${\mathcal S}$ since ${\mathcal S}$ contains no decreasing functions (see http://mathoverflow.net/questions/17614.)  Any solution to this problem is a linear space containing no injective functions.

Comment: In the previous comment, the full stop was taken as a part of the url - however, the intention was clearly to link to this post: [solving $f(f(x))=g(x)$](https://mathoverflow.net/q/17614).